# How to allign 3 divs next to each other in the middle?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs next to each other, but they aren't very nice alligned.
They are leaning towards the top instead of the middle.

What I want: 
[image]

what is now:
[image]

As you can see, the current one isn't alligned very good.The paragraphs needs to be higher and so on. This may seem like a subtle thing, but when you open it in different sizes of screens it looks very unorganized and messy.

So basically how to make it look like the first picture ?

Anyone got ideas ?

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 63px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 05% 00% 00% 02%;
}

.imageleft {
  float: left;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 5% 00% 2% 00%;
  width: 50%;
}

.imageright {
  float: right;
  margin: 02% -10% 0% 00%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="methods" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Methods</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="motivation" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Motivation</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flexbox approach then you can vertically align the children of the container, comments in code:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center; /* this vertically aligns the contents */
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
    width: 25%;
}

.paragraphs {
    padding: 0 5%; /* space between cells */
    flex-grow: 1; /* takes rest of space, best not to use 50% in case 25% + 50% + 300px > 100% */
}

.imageright {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="methods" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
            <span class="smalltext">Methods</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraphs">

        Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
        IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

    </div>
    <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="motivation" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
            <span class="smalltext">Motivation</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraphs">

        Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
        IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

    </div>
    <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: Im trying your code out now to check for errors, ps: Relax, I didn't downvote you, somebody else did

Comment: Ohh, yea I found that weird as well. I thought my question was different as well :S 
on topic: it looks good, my only problem is that the images appear really small, probably because I use it in wordpress, so that kinda is a bummer.